# how get dynamically droppable div id

Tags: jquery, droppable

I have a dropable div in which i make dynamically divs.I want to know dynamically in which inner div my element dropped to get that specific div id.

Answer (score 3):

Lucky

this is `HTML code` for my testing fro `Drag and Drop`

```
<div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="drag1">
    drag
</div>

<div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="drag2">
    drag
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    drop
</div>​
```

this is `CSS`

.

```
draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

#droppable {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
```

following `jquery` for `get droppable div id`

```
$('.draggable').draggable();
$('#droppable').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {        
        alert('drop id:'+ $(this).attr('id'));
    }
});​
```

See the following link for example: http://jsfiddle.net/YdcWt/5/

```
}
​
```